# Unique username and not unique email in django rest api

Tags: django-rest-framework

i am using an AbstractEmailUser from authtools.models for authentication in django rest api.

```
class User(AbstractEmailUser):
    user_name=models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=100)
```

i need to make unique username and not unique email.how can i do it?thanks in advance.

Comment: I just wonder, why do you need `authtools`? Do you have any spectacular reason for it? You can use your own User model inherited from `AbstractBaseUser`.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to inherit from `AbstractBaseUser`. Here is an example

```
class BasicUserModel(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=False) # or skip unique

    objects = UserManager() # you will need to define admin in this class
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```